# Swipe Views with Tabs: Modification required

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, android-tabs, horizontal-scrolling

I have implemented Swipe Views with Tabs from the Android's official website: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

I want to make two modifications to this code:

1. The Tab bar on the top shows three different tabs. On top left; the previous tab, on top right; the next tab and on top mid; the current/selected tab. I want to hide the previous and the next tabs. I want it to show only the current/selected tab bar.
2. In this code, each tab has only one fragment. I want Tab 2 to have 3 fragments lined horizontally. What I want is, if I swipe on from the top on the Tabs, I will go directly to the next/previous Tabs. But if I swipe on the screen, below the Tabs, I should be able to swipe three times for tab two before I reach tab 3. To elaborate: I need horizontally scroll-able List-views in each fragment.

Is this the right direction for this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your first point, but about grouping several fragments under the same tab, you can do it by adding your own listeners for tabs pressed and for viewPager swipe, instead of letting the view Pager implement that logic. Here is an example:

```
//setup tabs
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab("Prev"));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab("Current"));
    mTabLayout.addTab(mTabLayout.newTab("Next"));

    //Listen for pressed tabs
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            if (mDissableTabListener) {
                return;
            }

            if (tab.getPosition() == 0) {
                //go to first position
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 1){
               //i.e: go to your first tab at the center
               ,ViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            } else if (tab.getPosition() == 2) {
                //go to last position
                if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() -1) {
                    //we are in the last tab, so move to first position
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                }
            }
        }

        ...
    });

    //Now use a OnViewPagerListener to change selected tab when there is a swipe
    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                //avoid the TabSelectedMethod to be called (it would change the viewPager current item)
                mDissableTabListener = true;
            if (position == mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() -1){
                //When swipe to last 
                mTabLayout.getTabAt(2).select();

            } else if (position == 0){
                //select first tab
                mTabLayout.getTabAt(0).select();

            } else {
                //select center tab
                mTabLayout.getTabAt(1).select();
            }
            mDissableTabListener = false;
        }

        ...
    });
```